# Laravel - postman return error 500 internal server error

Tags: laravel, postman

im trying to return error message according to the exceptions types:

i have this code in my App\Exception\Handler.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Exceptions;

use Exception;
use App\Traits\ApiResponser;
use Asm89\Stack\CorsService;
use Illuminate\Database\QueryException;
use Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException;
use Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException;
use Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException;
use Illuminate\Auth\Access\AuthorizationException;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler as ExceptionHandler;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException;

class Handler extends ExceptionHandler
{
    use ApiResponser;
    /**
     * A list of the exception types that should not be reported.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $dontReport = [
        //
    ];

    /**
     * A list of the inputs that are never flashed for validation exceptions.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $dontFlash = [
        'password',
        'password_confirmation',
    ];

    /**
     * Report or log an exception.
     *
     * This is a great spot to send exceptions to Sentry, Bugsnag, etc.
     *
     * @param  \Exception  $exception
     * @return void
     */
    public function report(Exception $exception)
    {
        parent::report($exception);
    }

    /**
     * Render an exception into an HTTP response.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Exception  $exception
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function render($request, Exception $exception)
    {
        $response = $this->handleException($request, $exception);

        app(CorsService::class)->addActualRequestHeaders($response, $request);

        return $response;
    }

    public function handleException($request, Exception $exception)
    {
        if ($exception instanceof ValidationException) {
            return $this->convertValidationExceptionToResponse($exception, $request);
        }

        if ($exception instanceof ModelNotFoundException) {
            $modelo = strtolower(class_basename($exception->getModel()));
            return $this->errorResponse("No existe ninguna instancia de {$modelo} con el id especificado", 404);
        }

        if ($exception instanceof AuthenticationException) {
            return $this->unauthenticated($request, $exception);
        }

        if ($exception instanceof AuthorizationException) {
            return $this->errorResponse('No posee permisos para ejecutar esta acción', 403);
        }

        if ($exception instanceof NotFoundHttpException) {
            return $this->errorResponse('No se encontró la URL especificada', 404);
        }

        if ($exception instanceof MethodNotAllowedHttpException) {
            return $this->errorResponse('El método especificado en la petición no es válido', 405);
        }

        if ($exception instanceof HttpException) {
            return $this->errorResponse($exception->getMessage(), $exception->getStatusCode());
        }

        if ($exception instanceof QueryException) {
            $codigo = $exception->errorInfo[1];

            if ($codigo == 1451) {
                return $this->errorResponse('No se puede eliminar de forma permamente el recurso porque está relacionado con algún otro.', 409);
            }
        }

        if ($exception instanceof TokenMismatchException) {
            return redirect()->back()->withInput($request->input());
        }

        if (config('app.debug')) {
            return parent::render($request, $exception);            
        }

        return $this->errorResponse('Falla inesperada. Intente luego', 500);
    }

    /**
     * Convert an authentication exception into an unauthenticated response.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException  $exception
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    protected function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $exception)
    {
        if ($this->isFrontend($request)) {
            return redirect()->guest('login');
        }
        return $this->errorResponse('No autenticado.', 401);        
    }

    /**
     * Create a response object from the given validation exception.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException  $e
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     */
    protected function convertValidationExceptionToResponse(ValidationException $e, $request)
    {
        $errors = $e->validator->errors()->getMessages();

        if ($this->isFrontend($request)) {
            return $request->ajax() ? response()->json($errors, 422) : redirect()
                ->back()
                ->withInput($request->input())
                ->withErrors($errors);
        }

        return $this->errorResponse($errors, 422);
    }

    private function isFrontend($request)
    {
        return $request->acceptsHtml() && collect($request->route()->middleware())->contains('web');
    }
}
```

i have this code in my file App\Traits\ApiResponser:

```
<?php

namespace App\Traits;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;

trait ApiResponser
{
    private function successResponse($data, $code)
    {
        return response()->json($data, $code);
    }

    protected function errorResponse($message, $code)
    {
        return response()->json(['error' => $message, 'code' => $code], $code);
    }

    protected function showAll(Collection $collection, $code = 200)
    {
        return $this->successResponse(['data' => $collection], $code);
    }

    protected function showOne(Model $instance, $code = 200)
    {
        return $this->successResponse(['data' => $instance], $code);
    }
}
```

i have this in postman when i try to return a user that doesnt exist:

[image]

but i should get this error message in json:

"No existe ninguna instancia de usuario con el id especificado"

Comment: Error 500 means there is a problem with your code or server configuration. You should display/log the error. Only display in development environments and log it always.

Comment: Check the error log.

Comment: where do i see that? in laravel.log?

Comment: i have to change all the Exceptions parameters by Throwable, thats make the validation work

Comment: Log files are in storage/logs folder. laravel.log is the default filename.